# Why doesn't fTools Line to Polygon work?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

I am working new with QGIS (Version 2.8.2 / Window 8.2) and try to make Polygon from Line (see example picture 1[image]) with the fTool LineToPolygon, but it doesn't work (see picture 2[image: after use the tool - wrong plg]).

I work with complex geological maps and should make PLG from Line like in ArcGIS.

Comment: It depends on how the lines were digitized (order, intersections, ...), not on software

Comment: You expect something from line to polygon what it is not capable for.

Answer (score 2):

Line to polygon connects the first and the last point of each polyline.
It doesn't maintain topology. To solve the task you need a GIS handling topology like GRASS.

Comment: Thank you for your help, finely i managed to make polygon in GRASS (I cleared the dangles before by hand..). How I remove dangles (v.clean.rmdangles) outside the boundery (after use v.clean.brake), see picture 1?  I couldn't do it.

Comment: Did you set trashold for rmdangles? Give a negative treshold to remove all dangles. It doesn't care about the boundary.